# boost::filesystem normalize filename

Tags: boost, portability, boost-filesystem

I need normalize file names such that it don't contain any non-portable characters in it. There is `portable_file_name` but that just checks and returns bool. I need to **anyhow** convert the given string to a portable name to create files.

Is there any reusable works ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean some characters (*:;\"?<>/\|) are acceptable as file name or path name characters on some operating systems (Mac OS 9 for instance) but are not acceptable on others (such as Windows XP). Is that correct?

If so, you should probably do the character conversion yourself. I've done this in the past by using a regex to find and replace the unacceptable file name characters with a dash or something that works on all target operating systems. Then, you may safely use the files on both.

Comment: obviously that small utility function can be written very easily. but I want to avoid because why reinvent the same wheel if the same reusable already exists and being practiced.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

boost::filesystem3::path portable_file_name;

portable_file_name.normalize();

Comment: just checked, this does not remove special characters from the filename

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with so far is:

```
for (auto &c:name)
    {
        char test[] = { c,0 };
        if (!boost::filesystem::portable_file_name(test))
        {
            c = '_';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the important steps in doing this is converting file names like `./file` or ones pointing to symbolic links into filenames that work on other platforms which might not have these concepts. Boost v1.48.0+ actually [has the following functions](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#canonical) to do so:

```cpp
path canonical(const path& p, const path& base = current_path());
path canonical(const path& p, system::error_code& ec);
path canonical(const path& p, const path& base, system::error_code& ec);
```

This usually involves converting relative paths into absolute ones. These functions are also often called before performing security checks (e.g. is the requested file within the web-root directory of a web server?).

Note that `cannonical()` requires the file to exist.